# Android touchhandler priority

Tags: java, android, xml, touch

So first off, I got this snippet of code working in an empty activity, it just calls for every time when I touch the device.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("touch");
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

But as soon as I apply this snippet of code to an activity which also has a `GridViewPager`, the listener doesn't report any touch events.

So my guess is, that all touch Events are getting blocked by the `GridViewPager` and my listener is not getting anything.

Is there a way how I can fix that?

Comment: Is it required to identify different touches individually or you just need a listener when user has interacted??

Comment: I actually need a longClickListener to achieve this : https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit.html